# How to define a color scale conditional format in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to set up a color scale conditional format on a column of data in Excel using C#. I have already successfully added other conditional format rules but I do not understand how to set this one up. 
Here is a conditional rule which I have added which works:

```
Excel.Range Rng = workSheet.get_Range("H2", "J" + ExcelRowcount.ToString());                Excel.FormatConditions rule2 = Rng.FormatConditions;

Excel.FormatCondition between = (Excel.FormatCondition)rule2.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue, Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween, 0.049999, 0.15, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

Excel.Interior interior3 = between.Interior;
interior3.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.LavenderBlush);
```

But now I am trying to make it a color scale rule and I do not understand how to format the long excel function, this is what I have so far

```
Excel.Range range = workSheet.get_Range("L2", "L" +ExcelRowcount.ToString());
Excel.FormatConditions rule3 = range.FormatConditions;

Excel.FormatCondition colorscale = (Excel.FormatCondition)rule3.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlColorScale, Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlColorScale, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The values in the column are the results of some computations and are not known before hand so I need the rule to scale from high to low values.
I have not been able to fine and example of this `Excel.XlFormatConditionType` used any where so if some one could help me out with this that would be really great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue and for me the following worked for setting the colorscales:

```
MySheet = MyBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

Excel.ColorScale cfColorScale = (Excel.ColorScale)(MySheet.get_Range("B15", "K34").FormatConditions.AddColorScale(3));
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[1].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueLowestValue;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[1].FormatColor.Color = 0x000000FF;  // Red

cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValuePercentile;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].Value = 50;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].FormatColor.Color = 0x00FFCC00;  // yellow

cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[3].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueHighestValue;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[3].FormatColor.Color = 0x0000FF00;  // green
```

I am myself quite new to C# and still learning... hence I cannot elaborate on the solution as I adapted this from code I found on google-code ->

https://code.google.com/p/innovtech/source/browse/trunk/InnovTech/InnovTech.Localization/ExcelFile.cs?spec=svn94&r=94

Hope it might help?